# Number of oranges.

Tags: prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

The problem is as follows:

> Dividing the number of oranges by any odd digit and you end up with the next smallest even digit left over. What is the smallest number of oranges?

Let $N$ be the number of oranges. Then dividing by any odd number and setting it equal to the next smallest even number we obtain

$$\frac{N}{2n+1} = 2n  \implies N = 2n(2n+1)$$

The smallest is when $n = 1$. So $N=6$

Apparently the answer is not 6, but 314. Here is the justification for that answer, which I would like an explanation of.

Numerically, for each odd digit $n$ we divide by, we have $n-1$ left over. *So add an orange. Then the number is divisible by $3,5,7$ and $9$.* [This I don't understand]. The case of 3 is covered by 9. So the number is divisible without remainder by $5,7$ and $9$. These are all mutually prime so the smallest such number above $0$ is $5.7.9 = 315$. *One fewer would be $314$.* [why?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example, you are told that when you divide by $7$ you have $6$ left over.  If you add an orange the number will be divisible by $7$.  The same applies to $3,5,9$.  This justifies the claim that one more than the number of oranges must be a multiple of $5,7, \text { and } 9$.  $5 \cdot 7 \cdot 9=315$

Comment: But surely it would also hold for $11, 13,...$ ? why stop at 9?

Comment: Because those are not digits.

Comment: AHHHHHHH! I see. okay. damn. Thanks